# Yii Form add more element functionality

Tags: yii

I have created a Form in Yii, which takes user information, like Name, mobile, email and his location preference like city, zipcode which is multiple like with add more option.
[image]

currently i am using jQuery to give add more functionality, and at model i am using array validator. But i want Zipcode to be numeric and required, and City required.

I there any way to achive this in Yii.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say that in your form the variables are named zip1, zip2 and city1, city2 and the form is named infoForm

```
 public function rules()
 {
     return array(
                /*other rules here*/
                array('zip1,zip2,city1,city1', 'required', 'on' => 'initform'),
                array('zip1,zip2', 'integerOnly', 'on' => 'initform'),
            );
 }
```

Check out the [wiki](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/56/)

Comment: i have already done this, but its giving problem in case of multiple element.